# Programmatically debug Google’s V8 engine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

Is there a way to programmatically debug (inspect) Google’s V8 engine in a running chrome instance?
I know about the [V8 Inspector API](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Debugging-over-the-V8-Inspector-API) but I only figured out how to inspect a locally compiled version of V8 (not the one actually used by the browser). Is there a way to attach my inspection scrtipt to a running instance of the Chrome/Chromium browser? 
My google search did not find any helpful advice.

Maybe some context of my project might help:
I want to log ALL JavaScript function calls (i.e. the full stack trace of any given script). Is there may be a better way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

As Rodolph suggested on the mailing list: try the existing `--trace` flag. You can start Chrome with `--js-flags="--trace"`. Be prepared for lots of output!

Comment: Thanks! I saw the posting on the mailing list.

Comment: what quantity of "lots of output" are we talking about here? cuz this flag got my chrome dev tools frozen for a while, then came back alive with a significant drag, without any output from v8 appearing on console.

Comment: The output goes to stdout, not to the DevTools console, so you'll have to start Chrome from a terminal. How much it is depends on the page you're loading; on JS-heavy sites it can easily be a million lines just for the initial load.